# Subexponential size of string to prove $\{xy : x,y \in \{0,1\}^\star, |x| = |y|, x \ne y\}$ is not regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

In the standard proof of this language not being regular using the Pumping Lemma for Regular languages, one picks $0^p 1^p 0^{p+p!} 1^p$ where $p$ is the pumping constant and using that can derive the string $0^{p+p!}1^p0^{p+p!}1^p$ (since $p$ divides $p!$ for every $p$, thus proving the language is not regular.

Is there a string that has length subexponential in $p$ (or even polynomial) to show this language is not regular using the Pumping Lemma?